# ngClick on mdDialog's action button not triggering controller function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, mddialog

I am trying to undertsand angular dialogs. I have created a very simple code to display a custom alert dialog. I am trying to pass a string message to the dialog. Dialog has an OK button which shoudl close it.

The message data is being passed correctly. However for some reason, the OK button is not triggering the dialog controller's function.

Here is my code

**Alert.html - Contains template for Alert dialog**

```
<md-dialog>
    <md-dialog-content>
        {{message}}
    </md-dialog-content>

    <md-dialog-actions>
        <md-button ng-click="alertFunc">
            OK
        </md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
</md-dialog>
```

**AlertCtrl.js - Contains Controller for Alert Dialog**

```
app.controller('AlertCtrl', function ($scope, $mdDialog, message) {
    $scope.message = message

    $scope.alertFunc = function () {
        console.log("Closing Alert Dialog")
        $mdDialog.hide()
    }
})
```

**DialogService.js - Contains API to launch alert dialog**

```
app.service('DialogService', function($mdDialog) {

    // Launch Alert Dialog
    this.alert = function (message) {

        // Show Dialog
        $mdDialog.show({    templateUrl: 'Alert.html',
                            controller: 'AlertCtrl',
                            clickOutsideToClose: true,
                            locals: { message: message }
        })
    }
})
```

The log inside alertFunc never shows up.

I also tried putting `controllerAs : 'ctrl'` inside the `$mdDialog.show`. Then I changed the alertFunc declaration to `this.alertFunc = function...` and changed `ng-click='ctrl.alertFunc'`. However this did not work as well.

Can someone help me figure out the problem.

Thank You

Comment: Can you put this in a plunker?

Comment: Hi Mike... I was putting this in plunker and i suddenly realized i was missing a () inside ng-click. This is working now. Thanks for your comment. Wouldn't have happened without it. So much for 2 hours of brainstorming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `ng-click="alertFunc()"` instead of `ng-click="alertFunc"`. 2 hours of effort and a stupid parenthesis.

Amazing how ignorant a programmer can get.